# Django, call the same view function with and without parameter

Tags: python, django

I want to pass the image ID to the same view function and pass the Image to the template for display.

In my analysis app urls.py I have used

```
path('', views.image_analysis, name='home'),
path('<int:id>/', views.image_analysis, name='image_display'),
```

The view function is

**What should I do there to get the id in the function. If I do like  def image_analysis(request, id) its giving error.**

```
def image_analysis(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        post_id = Image_upload.objects.get(id=id)

    all_images = Image_upload.objects.filter(user=request.user)

    return render(request,
                'analysis/home.html',
                {'images': all_images}
                )
```

In the home.html template file.

```
{% block content %}

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <h2>Images</h2>
        <ul class="list-group">
        {% for image in images %}

            <li class="list-group-item"><a href="{% url 'analysis:image_display' image.id %}">{{image.image_name}} -</a> {{image.status}}</li>



        {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-8">  Single Image will come here.</div>
  </div>
```

The template HTML file is having 2 blocks the left one is with all the images from the user on clicking I want to display the image in the same place.

Can you please help me.

Comment: What is the error that you're getting?

Comment: If I use def image_analysis(request,id=None): in the view function I'm getting "Image_upload matching query does not exist."  and without 'id=None' in view function  "TypeError at /analysis/
int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'builtin_function_or_method'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make your view function as the following:

```
def image_analysis(request, id=None):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        try:
            post_id = Image_upload.objects.get(id=id)
        except:
            <do the logic that you need if id doesnt exist in url>

    all_images = Image_upload.objects.filter(user=request.user)

    return render(request,
                'analysis/home.html',
                {'images': all_images}
                )
```

If you are giving id in the function definition, then it will always look for it to be given, since it is optional for you, we put it as `id=None`.

Inside the function you are performing a query with that id, but obviously there wont be any `id = None` in the DB table. hence you need to catch that exception and do the logic for what happens if there is no id in url inside that `except` block.

Comment: Thanks to all, both the approaches are working but what will be the good practice.

Comment: Both are a good enough methods, no doubt on that. This answer is more closer towards your approach of not using kwargs and args.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the id in the `image_analysis` function by using `kwargs`.

Change your function like so:

```
def image_analysis(request, *args, **kwargs):
    id = kwargs.get('id')
    if request.method == 'GET' and id:
        post_id = Image_upload.objects.get(id=id)
    else:
        post_id = None # Replace with relevant code

    all_images = Image_upload.objects.filter(user=request.user)

    return render(request,
                'analysis/home.html',
                {'images': all_images}
                )
```

In case after this change, you get a matching query does not exist error, try swapping the URLs.

```
path('<int:id>/', views.image_analysis, name='image_display'),
path('', views.image_analysis, name='home'),
```